# Ошибка pytesseract, TypeError: Unsupported image object

Tags: python, распознавание-символов

Написал простой код:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string('test.png'))
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\Python\list10\test.py", line 8, in <module>
>     print(pytesseract.image_to_string('test.png'))
>   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 286, in image_to_string
> return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)
>   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 184, in run_and_get_output
> temp_name, input_filename = save_image(image)
>   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 101, in save_image
> image = prepare(image)
>   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 97, in prepare
> raise TypeError('Unsupported image object')
> TypeError: Unsupported image object
> ```

Детали:

- Python 2.7.15
- Windows 10
- tesseract установлен (в файле `pytesseract.py` изменения внёс `tesseract_cmd = 'D:\Python27\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'`)
- текст распознавания простой (английский, без шума)

Прошу помочь разобраться!!!

---

Получилось на версии Python 3.6.5! На версии Python 2.7.15 так и не получилось....

Comment: вы передаете в image_to_string строку, вместо объекта типа Image. Исправьте на `pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))`

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Пробовал написание кода таким способом, ошибка всё равно появляется...